# TFS 2012 - Build Agent Folders Not Being Removed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild

We have a TFS 2012 Build Agent running automated builds in DEV environment using ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml Build Definition from Release Management for Visual Studio 2013.

Builds succeed, however the build agent workspace files/folders remain after files/folders are dropped in a separate location.

Build agent workspace is set to:

```
$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
```

We want everything under $(BuildAgentId) to be deleted after each build.

"Clean Workspace" is set to "ALL" in the build definition, but files/folders are still not deleted.

Build Agent service is using an AD account with local admin rights.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean all means that the workspace is changed at the beginning of the build. Files are left at the end to facilitate this.

You can create a PowerShell that change the files and run It post build.

Comment: No built-in way to clear build agent folders after each build?

Comment: Not after. But there is a built in way to do PowerShell, so you can do whatever you like.